# How to open files in compressed format. ZFC

Tags: file, zip, compression

How I can open files in compressed format. ZFC in windows?

The format is this

http://file.downloadatoz.com/zfc-file-extension/

I'm trying to unzip this file

http://fluxxy.com.br/rom.zfc

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 1):

This file format seems to be a proprietary format.
It contains no header related to well known archive format so you won't be able to uncompress ti unless you find an RFC-alike documentation.
You won't get through it easilysince you'll need binary mapping from Alistair to do so.